# https://vmap0.tiles not working

Tags: postgis, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am using vmap0.tiles with  OpenLayers. Five months ago I could still access https://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?  using https, but for two months it  has not worked anymore.

What is wrong?

Comment: It looks like https:// is not supported, it only works using http://

Comment: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo/ticket/2308 might be relevant. You could try and raise a new issue on Trac stating that https isn't working anymore.